# Is it possible to Delete Cecil Beckum?

Tags: discussion

It is sad enough that Cecil Beckum left. But is it ethical to Delete Cecil Beckum? Is that like a form of murder - to delete a C.SE user? I heard the [Penalty Box for C.SE](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) box but not a death c.se box. Is there?

Comment: People come. People go. Let them come and go as they wish. They do not have an obligation to post on Christianity.SE and write "I am going to die" on their profiles when they are going to die.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will you please delete me](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/will-you-please-delete-me)

Answer (score 10):

Your association between the deletion of an account and murder is nothing short of preposterous. Enough said.

Besides that, it is not relevant as it is Cecil himself that has requested deletion of [his own account](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/5867/bye). Presuming we verify that this is his permanent wish, I don't see how we could charitably do anything else.

Comment: Preposterous? In honor of Cecil Beckum delete my account.

Comment: @Aaron Yes preposterous. Removing some digital bits associated with an online profile (at the author's request no less) is not even remotely similar to murder in any way. What you do with your profile is up to you (if you wish to remove it there is [a standard procedure for you to follow](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)) but don't you think you are being bit over-reactionary here?

Comment: @Caleb It's frustrating to write out answers just to get them deleted. Especially when there's no real reason behind it, but a whim from a moderator. It makes me not want to come back either, which is probably what I'll do. C.SE gives me an opportunity to voice my opinions and beliefs, once that is taken away without reason, there is no reason to visit C.SE. anymore.

Comment: @jlaverde This is not about "whim of a moderator" or "no reason". There is a reason and you should learn about what is and isn't acceptable here so you don't waste time on posts that may not stand. If you think my judgement is in error, have other concerns or are just confused the thing to do is ask a new question here on meta (not comment on an unrelated post). The community can review the actions I have taken and everybody can weigh in with opinions.

Comment: @SteelyDan If that is a point you want to express here on meta you may do so in your own question where people can likewise express their opinions about your idea.

Comment: @jlaverde while I sympathize with your position, having often been in it myself, "... opportunity to voice my opinions and beliefs" is very troubling.  Christianity.SE, as I have learned along the way, is not a place to soapbox a theology.

Answer (score 5):

They will be back, trust me.  As many of you know, I deleted my account once upon a time.  After 3 months or so, I said, "well, let's just read and see what's going on over there" after another month or so, I recreated my account starting with 100 rep again.  Christianity.SE can be a frustrating place.  Especially early on when things were quite more dynamic.  Questions posted back then would not be able to be posted today, etc.  Most of my questions back then were offtopic then and even more so today.

So, I do attempt to help the newbies and the mods by making suggestions to those questions and answers that I have empirically seen shot down for one reason or another.  Unfortunately sometimes people (Cecil for example) believe that comes across condescending. I am sorry that it comes across that way, however that is not the case at all.  If you know nothing of "die-hard" freemasons, know this, we feel that we're all on the same level.

Comment: I often wish that user1054 could be reassociated with your account...